# Best way to create a server to receive posted images from Iphone

Tags: http, webserver

My goal is to have a user send a photo from their iPhone to a server for processing.

How would I create a server that accepts HTTP Post requests.

Comment: If you want a server accesible through the internet, you can best buy some cheap hosting. They take care of the DNS and security for you. Then you can write a simple script that fetches the HTTP post request and inserts it into a DB

Comment: This question is not related to iPhone or Xcode.

Comment: Do you know any server side scripting languages? You can write your own server using any of the scripting languages such as PHP, ASP etc.

Comment: Sorry it isn't related. Is it possible to use mac web sharing to receive images?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSURLConnection` to send a HTTP request from your iPhone to your server.

If you are using PHP, you can accept POSTed fields using `$_POST['fieldname']`

This link should help you get started:
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Comment: Thank you, currently I have the iPhone HTTP post ready for the most part. I am new to the server part of this though.

Answer (score 0):

With PHP you can do something like this:

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST[someKey]))
    {
        // do something funky   
    }

?>
```

Like others have said, buy a simple web hosting server like Hostgator (http://www.hostgator.com/) then in the cPanel backend they provide you, create an FTP account  to upload the files or you can use the cPanel to upload the file.

Upload your PHP script to the server and test it.

Here's a tutorial for writing iPhone + PHP web service:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/2941/how-to-write-a-simple-phpmysql-web-service-for-an-ios-app

For posting to the server you can use something like AFNetworking (https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)

A sample code to upload image using AFNetworking (stolen from the above link if you didn't click it :D):

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api-base-url.com"];
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"avatar.jpg"], 0.5);
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"/upload" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"avatar" fileName:@"avatar.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
}];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request] autorelease];
[operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
    NSLog(@"Sent %lld of %lld bytes", totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite);
}];
[operation start];
```

Comment: Thank you, are you suggesting not using NSURLConnection then?

Comment: Try both ways and see which one is easier for you.